# Change composer global path (Windows)

Tags: php, windows, path, composer-php

Composer uses `%APPDATA%\Composer` directory by default for global packages.
So I need to add `%APPDATA%\Composer\vendor\bin` path to my user PATH environment variable.

Can I change installation directory to something like `C:\php\composer`? How can I do it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found an answer in the source code: https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Factory.php#L45

So environment variable `COMPOSER_HOME` must be defined as `C:\php\composer`.

Answer (score 33):

On Windows, when [global install](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global) of a library / package is done, composer stores the package in a `Composer` directory inside `windows **application data folders** which by default is` C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Roaming`.

To change this folder to say `C:\php\composer`, create a `COMPOSER_HOME` environmental variable with the value set to `C:\php\composer`.

The steps below explain how environmental variables are added in Windows. * Press **Windows Key + Pause Break** then click `Advanced system Settings`

[image: Windows system settings]
<sub>(source: [w3guy.com](https://media.w3guy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/windows-system-settings.png))</sub>

Click the `Environmental variables` button.

[image: Environmental variable button]
<sub>(source: [w3guy.com](https://media.w3guy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/environmental-variables-link.png))</sub>

Under `System variables`, click `New...` button and add the environmental variable like so:

[image: Add environmental variables in Windows]
<sub>(source: [w3guy.com](https://media.w3guy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/add-windows-environmental-variable.png))</sub>

You might want to restart your PC for this to take effect.

Credit: http://w3guy.com/change-composer-global-package-install-folder-windows/

Comment: Thanks! Just reopening cmd will do though

Answer (score 4):

Go to folder

(C:\Users(your user)\AppData\Roaming\Composer )

Then create new folder (vendor)

and

in vendor create (bin) and copy (C:\composer\composer.phar) to (bin) .